# What else is limited on minecraft xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

Ok so mobs are limited to a world as well as paintings and item frames. ..how much more stuff is limited?, because I'm building something really big and each suite has like 3-4 beds and about 2 paintings (normally used for tv screens and pc screens) and sure as hell don't wanna run short of beds, redstone, or just other blocks and items before the big penthouse is built with no beds or tv.

Answer (score 2):

When Mojang ported minecraft to the x360, they made many restrictions for performance reasons. I remember when it first came out running experiments in creative, and being very disappointed. I expect many things have changed since 2012.

Only 'entities' are limited, regular blocks don't have any limitations. Entities are usually classified as anything which moves, but there are a couple of exceptions (like paintings and item frames). There is no limitation on beds. For a complete list of entity types see the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Entity). The best way to determine the exact limit for each entity type, is to jump into creative and test it out.

The biggest disappointments for me were

- Primed TNT is limited to 20, so no massive TNT cannons. If you ignite a TNT block when the limit has been reached, the block will simply disappear :(
  See these images, [before ignition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiyPM.jpg) and [after ignition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw0mf.jpg)
- Dropped item limit, so no large wheat farms. If you drop an item, when the limit has been reached, the oldest item will disappear.
- Mob spawn limit (both hostile and friendly), so no large mob farms. If the limit has been reached, no more will spawn.
- Also red stone doesn't propagate to unloaded chunks, so no massive circuits like you can do in the PC version..

Answer (score 0):

As you may or may not already know, Minecraft worlds are separated into chunks, which are 64 blocks by 64 blocks in the x and z directions, and extend from bedrock to the build limit (y = 256 if I remember correctly). Within all loaded chunks (meaning it's either the chunk containing the world spawn or there is currently a player in the chunk or close enough to one of the edges to load it), the following things have a limit on how many can be present:

- Mobs
- Paintings
- Item frames
- Items in item frames (if you put up the maximum number of item frames, you may not be able to actually fill them all)

There may be others that are limited that I'm not aware of, but these are the things I most frequently run into the build limit with.